# Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Router> when using Okta for React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, okta

I've followed a sitepoint tutorial by Lee Brandt for a React App with User Authentication using okta.

First I received this:

> **ERROR** in ./src/app.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './components/auth/LoginPage' in
>   '/Users/COMPUTER/Desktop/okta-react-widget-sample/src'  @ ./src/app.js
>   3:17-55  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
>   ./app.js webpack: Failed to compile.

I have deleted the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file.

I then changed syntax and now have in my file:

```
import LoginPage from './components/auth/LoginPage';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Layout from './components/common/Layout';
import HomePage from './components/home/HomePage';
import AboutPage from './components/about/AboutPage';
import ContactPage from './components/contact/ContactPage';
import '../scss/site.scss';

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={ContactPage}/>
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
```

The NEW error is below. 
This is what I am getting:

ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for  (18:4)

```
16 <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
17 <Route path="/contact" component={ContactPage}/>
>18 </Route>
    ^
19 </Router>
20 document.getElementById('app')
21 )
```

@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./app.js
webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: please add [mcve] to your question by editing it

Comment: Have you reinstalled `node_module`?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I did not reinstall it. I did change some syntax. Now there is a different error. Is it best to repost  it in a new thread, for the different error?

Comment: No just edit this question, but do it after doing `sudo npm install`

Comment: Thanks @DhavalJardosh. I just edited it.

Comment: You have two strange square brackets in your file, here `[import LoginPage from './components/auth/LoginPage';` and there  `document.getElementById('app')][1]`

Comment: That was because of stack overflow. not the actual files. I can't copy the code here or stack overflow hides it for some reason...
I had to handwrite the terminal output, so was hiding that too. I've edited the above to remove the brackets.

Comment: oh ok. btw you have a running version of the code here: https://github.com/leebrandt/okta-react-widget-sample. Maybe you can spot the difference.

Comment: Ok , fixed the syntax error by looking at the difference in the github running version and now getting the original error:

ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/auth/LoginPage' in '/Users/NEWCOMPUTER/Desktop/okta-react-widget-sample/src'
 @ ./src/app.js 3:17-55
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./app.js
webpack: Failed to compile.